# What is the meaning of `echo ${#str}` in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

can someone explain this command to me

```
str=hello
echo ${#str}
```

this code counts the number of characters in the variable **str**. I want to know how it works what does the symbols $,# and {} means there

thanks.

Comment: You'll find the answer in `man bash`.  Look for _Parameter length_ in the section entitled _Parameter Expansion_.

Comment: Why downvotes without any comment? The question complete and clear and not as trivial as a lot of others here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'$' introduces parameter expansion, so here it "replaces" the variable with the actual value:

```
str=hello
echo $str
> hello
```

With the braces: {} you can define the boundaries of the parameter name. So: " parameter is followed by a character which is not to be interpreted as part of its name". For example this shows that "asdfg" is not part of the parameter name:

```
str=hello
echo ${str}asdfg
> helloasdfg
```

'#' just tells that you need the length of the value of that parameter.

```
str=hello
echo ${#str}asdfg
> 5asdfg
```

But as @John1024 said it's all in `Parameter Expansion` part of `man bash`

Comment: Or in the online documentation, which is quite comprehensive: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html